# how to retrieve location data in App Clip

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-appclips

Is it possible to prompt for and retrieve a users location inside of an App Clip? If so, how could it be done? I tried using CLocation Manager, but it seems to not be supported inside of App Clips. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Core Location to access the user's location in an app clip.  This is to protect the user's privacy.

You can embed a code in your app clip url and then, when launched, use that code to obtain an expected location.

Once you have the expected location you can use it to create a `CLCircularRegion` with a radius of up to 500m.

You can then confirm that the url that launched your app was acquired inside the region.

Apple has more detail and some sample code [available on their developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/confirming_the_user_s_physical_location)

Comment: I see, thank you. It's a little tricky for my use case because our NFC tags (used for invocation) are not in any pre-defined locations. We are looking to add some sort of "Send Location" button in our App Clip, do you think launching a web-page, and prompting the user for their location there could be practical?

Comment: You could try that. Web views are supported in app clips.